# C++ type qualifiers and equality

Tags: c++

Are `int&` and `int` the same type? if I use `is_same<int,int&>::value` i get `false` but `typeid(int).name() == typeid(int&).name()` are the same?

secondly the same question for `int` and `const int`?

Thirdly `int` and `int*`?

I can understand if `int` and `int*` are not as one actually stores the address of another object and works differently but I would have thought `int&` and `int` are as one is just an alias for another.

Keen to get some good commentary on this.

Comment: `int&` and `int` are not the same type. `int&` is a reference to an `int` same as `int*` is a pointer to an `int`. They themselves are not `int`'s

Comment: `typeid` strips off references and top-level `const` and `volatile` qualifiers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Paragraph 5.2.7/4 of the C++11 Standard:

> When typeid is applied to a type-id, the result refers to a std::type_info object representing the type of the type-id. **If the type of the type-id is a reference to a possibly cv-qualified type, the result of the typeid expression refers to a std::type_info object representing the cv-unqualified referenced type**. If the type of the type-id is a class type or a reference to a class type, the class shall be completely-defined.

Thus, `typeid(int)` and `typeid(int&)` will give the same result, although the two types are definitely different. Similarly, for the type system `int` and `int const` are different types, but the `typeid` operator ignores the `const` qualification. From Paragraph 5.2.7/5 of the C++11 Standard:

> The top-level cv-qualifiers of the glvalue expression or the type-id that is the operand of typeid are always ignored.

Finally, `int` and `int*` are again different types for the type system, and the `typeid` operator returns different results for them.

Answer (score 2):

Type qualifiers, (`const` and `volatile`), create different types.  `int` is a different type from `const int`.

So do references, pointers, and arrays. For example:

`int`, `int&`, `int[10]` and `int*` are all different types.

`T` is a different type from `std::remove_reference<T>::type` if `T` is a reference.

The `<typeinfo>` output of `typeid(int).name()` is platform-dependent and doesn't have to distinguish between reference/non-reference types.  However, the C++ type system *definitely* distinguishes between `T` and `T&`, as you've discovered through `type_traits`.

Comment: awesome one of the reasons I ask is how difficult is to get reliable typename information only VS 2012 does this I think

Comment: All compilers give _reliable_ typename info, they might give mangled names, but it's not unreliable

Answer (score 0):

[`std::type_info::name`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name) says nothing about identity. *If* you insist on using `typeid` to test for identity, try the following:

```
assert(typeid(T) != typeid(U));
```

This is using the defined [equality comparison operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/operator_cmp) on the `type_info` objects. But prepare for disappointment: the above assertion will fail for `T = int` and `U = int&` because of §5.2.7/4 (see Andy’s anser).

Comment: Cheers. One other thing i find a bit annoying is the fact decltype does not always return what i expect.

Comment: Although I was sure that they are all different datatypes i thought const and volatile just augmented what you can do on the type. Glad to get some good answers

Comment: @Blair Please have a look at the edit of my post, after I tried the code out. `typeid` behaves a bit counter-intuitive here. And yes, the same is true for `decltype`.